# Adding new item to database using ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I'm building a Pet Shop website using ASP.NET Core MVC (the latest version).

I have database with instructions for primary key and identity(1,1) (auto increment).

In my website,in order to check and see if my 'Create' method is working, I've created a page (a controller and view) of Create new animal and a page for the list of all the animals that I've got (Index controller). After clicking Submit on the create page, it's redirected to Index - where I should see the animal that I've added (this line wrote on SQL):

[image]

The problem is that I don't see anything added to my list (the photo above). After a few tries, I've tried to add animal directly in my SQL and I saw that it's got the number ID 22 - meaning that maybe I did succeeded to add new animal and I just don't see it?

I really don't know where my problem is and I would be happy to get help.

Controller:

```
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var petShopDataContext = _context.Animals.Include(a => a.Category);
        return View(await petShopDataContext.ToListAsync());
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAnimal()
    {
        var categories = await _categoryService.GetAnimalCategory();
        ViewBag.Categories = categories.Select(c => new SelectListItem(c.Name, c.CategoryId.ToString())).ToList();
        return View();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> CreateAnimal([FromForm] CreateAnimalViewModel vm)
    {
        vm.Animal.Category = await _categoryService.GetAsync(vm.Animal.CategoryId);
        _animalService.AddAnimalAsync(vm.Animal, vm.Photo);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

CreateAnimalViewModel:

```
public class CreateAnimalViewModel
{
    public Animal Animal { get; set; }
    public IFormFile Photo { get; set; }
}
```

Create Animal View:

```
@model PetShop.Client.Models.CreateAnimalViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "CreateAnimal";
}

<h4>Create New Animal</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="CreateAnimal" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Animal.Name" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Animal.Name" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Animal.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Animal.BirthDate" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Animal.BirthDate" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Animal.BirthDate" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Animal.Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Animal.Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Animal.Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Animal.Category">Category</label>
                <select asp-for="Animal.CategoryId" asp-items="ViewBag.Categories" class ="form-control" id="category"></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="Animal.CategoryId" />

                    <a asp-controller="Admin" asp-action="CreateCategory">
                        <input type="button" value="Add new category"/>
                    </a>

            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Photo" class="control-label"></label>
                <input type="file" asp-for="Photo" accept="image/*" class="form-control-file"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Photo" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Index View:

```
@model IEnumerable<PetShop.Data.Models.Animal>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h1>Index</h1>

<p>
    <a asp-action="CreateAnimal">Create New</a>
</p>
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BirthDate)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PhotoUrl)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Category)
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BirthDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.PhotoUrl)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.AnimalId">Edit</a> |
                <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.AnimalId">Details</a> |
                <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.AnimalId">Delete</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Animal Service:

```
 public async Task<Animal> AddAnimalAsync(Animal animal, IFormFile image)
 {
        var entity = _animalRepository.Add(animal);
        var path = await _imageService.UploadImage(image, animal);

        if (path != String.Empty)
        {
            return _animalRepository.Update(entity);
        }

        return entity;
}
```

Animal Repository:

```
public Animal Add(Animal entity)
{
    _context.Animals.Add(entity);
    _context.SaveChanges();
    return entity;
}
```

Comment: At a glance, you don't await the call to `_animalService.AddAnimalAsync(vm.Animal, vm.Photo)`

Comment: When I'm adding 'await' to this line I'm getting- SqlException and the command does not executed

Comment: And what is the error message in the exception?  Basically what's happening is the operation is failing.  Previously, by not awaiting the result, the code was ignoring that failure.  Now that you're able to see that it's failing, you need to catch the exception so you can log or observe it in some way.  It's telling you what the problem is.

Comment: I'm getting: SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'PhotoUrl', table 'PetShopData.dbo.Animals'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated. I understand what yoy are saying but I still don't get one thing - if the 'create' didn't work, why did I get auto Animal ID with the number 22 on SQL? Maybe I did added those items and can't see them?

Comment: The next step is for you to do some debugging.  When you add that record to the database, *is there* a value for `PhotoUrl`?  Do you expect there to be one?  Why?  The error itself is pretty simple... You're inserting a `NULL` value to a column which does not allow that.  Either update the database to allow `NULL` in that column or update the application to provide a value.

Comment: In this line `_animalService.AddAnimalAsync(vm.Animal, vm.Photo);
` are you getting `vm.Photo` value while submitting requiest?

Comment: Thank you David, I'm going to check what you said and fix my mistake. On my animalService I'm also handeling photo uploading, by using another service that I've built, I'm guessing that the problem is there.

Comment: Md Farid Uddin Kiron like David said, I didn't know that I'm getting null on PhotoUrl , only when I've added 'await' I saw it.

Comment: So could you please confirm that setting with `await` to handle locking resolve your problem or you are still getting the the exception?

Comment: Md Farid Uddin Kiron I confirm that using 'await' helped me! like I said to David, it gave me Excepction about the PhotoUrl value and I did manage to solve it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Glad to hear that your problem has resolved.